# Visual Basics Calculater hexadecimal and binary numbers

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

as an exercise for university we need to create a calculator with visual basic.
It has to be able to work with hexadecimal numbers and binary numbers.

My plan is to translate those to normal numbers, calculate and than translate them back, so i can use the simple +, -, *, / .

Unfortunately i wasn't able to find any translation between the number systems.
Is there anybody, who could send one in? It'd help me quite a lot.

Greetings Phil

Answer (score 0):

The [`Convert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert(v=vs.110).aspx) class:

```
 Dim fromHex As Long = Convert.ToInt64("beef", 16)
 Dim fromBin As Long = Convert.ToInt64("1011110", 2)
```